# Fastest way to sort an Array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, sorting, quicksort

Hi this is my problem I have an array of points P(x,y) and  I need to sort these points from the furthest to the closest, respect to the barycenter of a Polygon, this what I have done (I know this is a bad solution ) how can I do a better and aboveall faster solution?

```C#
List<C2DPoint> OrderedGripperPoints = new List<C2DPoint> { };

while(myGripperPoints.Count!=0) 
{
    double dist=-1;
    int index=-1;
    for(int k=0;k<myGripperPoints.Count;k++)
    {
        if(myGripperPoints[k].Distance(WorkScrap.GetCentroid())>=dist)
        {
            index = k;
            dist = myGripperPoints[k].Distance(WorkScrap.GetCentroid());
        }
    }

    OrderedGripperPoints.Add(myGripperPoints[index]);
    myGripperPoints.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

Thanks for your answers...

Comment: Is it possible to precompute distance at creation time of `C2DPoint`?

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan yeas it is

Comment: You can use Array.Sort too

Answer (score 4):

Use Linq to order points.

```
using System.Linq;

var sortedList = myGripperPoints.OrderBy(p => p.Distance(WorkScrap.GetCentroid())).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: It should be `OrderByDescending`, based on the question posted

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code:

**Point Class (assumed class definition)**

```
class Point
{
    public int X { get; set;}

    public int Y { get; set;}   
}
```

**Point EqualityComparer**

```
class PointEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Point>
{
    public bool Equals(Point p1, Point p2) { return p1.X == p2.X && p1.Y == p2.Y; }

    public int GetHashCode(Point p) { return p.X.GetHashCode() *31 + p.Y.GetHashCode()*23; }
}
```

**Create a Dictionary with Point as Key and Distance as value (assuming integer):**

```
Dictionary<Point,int> pointDictionary = 
new Dictionary<Point, int>(new PointEqualityComparer());
```

**Add Points as follows:**

```
Point p = new Point {X = <value>, Y = <value>};
pointDictionary.Add(p,p.Distance(WorkScrap.GetCentroid()));
```

**Order by Distance as follows:**

```
pointDictionary.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

1. Ordering is done by Distance in Descending order as expected
2. Result would be `List<KeyValuePair<Point,int>>`, where elements are in Descending order

Comment: This solution provides you much more fine grain control over the process of Ordering as many more properties can be part of the Dictionary <key,value> and can be used in the Ordered collection

Comment: @AntonínLejsek thanks for pointing out, is this one better. Guarantee of having unique hash still may not be there, but will reduce the clash